# flutter_pinput: FocusTapArea is not defined

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, flutter-pub

After upgrading to Flutter 3.1.x, the package `flutter_pinput` doesn't work anymore. Any suggestions would be helpful. It was working fine in flutter 2.x.x. I have tried repairing the cache using `flutter pub cache repair`and also cleaned the project cache using `flutter clean`.It still doesn't work.

```
 /C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pinput-2.2.11/lib/src/pinput_state.dart:334:14: Error: The method 'FocusTrapArea' isn't defined for the class '_PinputState'.
         - '_PinputState' is from 'package:pinput/src/pinput.dart' ('/C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pinput-2.2.11/lib/src/pinput.dart').
        Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FocusTrapArea'.
              child: FocusTrapArea(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        
        * Where:
        Script 'D:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
        
        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
        > Process 'command 'D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        
        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. 
        Run with --scan to get full insights.
        
        * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
        
        BUILD FAILED in 27s
        Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             29.0s
        Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Version Info:

```
Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.2085 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 74aef9ff87 (8 hours ago) • 2022-08-04 02:00:08 -0400
Engine • revision e32e0d217b
Tools • Dart 2.19.0 (build 2.19.0-62.0.dev) • DevTools 2.16.0
```

Comment: Can you include sample widget

Comment: Hey! it got fixed after switching to the stable channel. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to switch to the stable channel.

`flutter channel stable && flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Update your package [pinput](https://pub.dev/packages/pinput)

After updating the package run your application again.